# Reading a text file and comparing each line

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I have an assignment that has a txt file. I have to scan the first line and compare it to other line

```
(
BACCDEABCEEDCDABBAED
6734 BXCCDAABCEEDCDACBAED
7843 BADCXAABCEXXCDABBAED
2223 BCBAEACCDAEDCDABBAEA
2324 BACXDEABCEEDCDAABAED
3474 BACCDEABCEEDCDABBAED
3434 XADCDAABCEEDCDABBAED
6374 XXXXXCXXXXXXXXXXXAED
3332 BADCDEABCEEDCDADBCEX
3454 BACCXEABCEEDCXABBAED
0
)
```

How would I seperate the first for digits and compare the the [20](Correct_ answers) other letters with the first line of 20?

This is what I got so far.........

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char answer[20];

    char studentAnswer[20];

    int studentId[4];

    int x;

    int correct=0,wrong=0,notAttempted=0;

    FILE * in = fopen("/Users/MarkB/Desktop/ASSIGNMENT3/exam.txt", "r");
    FILE * out = fopen("/Users/MarkB/Desktop/ASSIGNMENT3/examRsults.txt", "w");

    fscanf(in,"%d",studentId);
    fscanf(in,"%s",answer);
    fscanf(in,"%s",studentAnswer);
    while (studentId !=0){
        for (x=0; x<20;x=x+1){
            if(answer[x]==studentAnswer[x]){
                correct=correct + 1;
            }
            if(answer[x]!=studentAnswer[x] && studentAnswer[x]!='X'){
                wrong=wrong + 1;
            }
            if(studentAnswer[x]=='X'){
                notAttempted=notAttempted + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(out,"--------Student Exam results------\n");

    fprintf (out,"%d",studentId[0]);



    fprintf (out,"Questions Correct: %d \n",correct);
    fprintf (out,"Questions Wrong: %d \n",wrong);
    fprintf (out,"Questions not attempted: %d \n",notAttempted);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no "this is what I got so far." Do you have a **specific** question? If not, research some bit. Is it **that** hard?

Comment: The first line of your input file (ignoring the `'('` ) is an alphabetical string. Your first read statement is `fscanf(in,"%d",studentId);` which is asking for an `int` and so won't read the first item, one thing you must do before you go any further is to check the return value from `fscanf()` **every time** which in case you never bothered to read the man page, is the number of fields successfully converted.

Comment: Insided the code block of `while (studentId !=0)` that variable `studentId` is not modified. In any case, why are you using `int studentId[4];` as if it were `int studentId;`?

Comment: When have trouble with file input  --> Step 1: check the return value from the `fscanf()`.  Is it as expected?  By doing so, your code will be more robust and you will save debugging time.  Hint, what did `fscanf(in,"%d",studentId);` return?  Why is it not 1?

Comment: `"BACCDEABCEEDCDABBAED"` will not fit in a `char answer[20];` as a string in C.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
fscanf(in,"%s",studentAnswer);
```

is not taking into account the id before the students' answers.  If the input file really does have '(' and ')' you must also account for skipping them.  You must also somehow compare the id given to the line you are on.  You have to compare the id you got in a while loop until you can read that students answers.